# Back to my Mac secure?

Tags: back-to-my-mac

Is Back to my Mac an encrypted and secure connection? Is there a good technical explanation how it works? Would you recommend to use it to connect to a home server via VNC?

Comment: Next time... you should probably try Googling first before asking a question, because if you had... I believe you would have found the very information presented in the answer.

Comment: Indeed, it was the top Google hit for "back to my mac security", for me.

Comment: Yes, you are right…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202312):

> Back to My Mac uses these methods to protect your security:
>
> - IPSec and SSL encrypt and secure communication between your Macs and the Back to My Mac servers. Anything you transfer between Macs is
>     protected.
> - Kerberos with digital certificates provide secure and trusted authentication to help verify identity. An added benefit: with
>     Kerberos, you won’t have to enter your user name and password every
>     time you connect to another Mac in your Back to My Mac network.
>
> You can make your network even more secure by changing a few optional
>   settings.